# In F#, how to pass a type name as a function parameter?

Tags: types, parameters, f#

I would like to pass a type name (such as `int`, or `string`, or even the name of a user-defined type) as a function parameter.  Currently I am doing the following:

```
type IntegerOrIntegerList =
    | Integer of int
    | IntegerList of int list

let f (n : int) (d : 'T) : IntegerOrIntegerList =
    match (box d) with
    | :? int as i -> Integer(n)
    | _ -> IntegerList([0 .. n])
```

But the presence of `d` above is adventitious.  What would be the idiomatic F# way to express the above logic?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a type arg:

```
let f<'T> (n : int) =
  if typeof<'T> = typeof<int> then Integer(n)
  else IntegerList([0 .. n])
```